# How to sample from a user-defined function that generates random numbers

Tags: r

I have written a function `x <- function() ...` that generates random numbers according to a distribution I'd like to study.

```
> x()
[1] 0.8947771
> x()
[1] 0.4478619
```

I can generate a list of 10 random numbers using `x` via a for loop:

```
> s <- c()
> for(i in 1:10) s <- c(s,x())
> s
 [1] 0.6035317 0.4556456 0.6063270 0.4567958 0.5805186 0.7688124 0.6722493
 [8] 0.3908357 0.4513608 0.2747064
```

However, this seems clumsy.  I would like to know: *is there a better way to create such a list?*

There are some succinct ways of generating lists numbers in R, such as `(1:10)^2` (which generates squares) and `runif(10,0,1)` (which generates uniformly random numbers between 0 and 1), `rnorm(10)` (which generates normal-distributed numbers) but I can't seem to get it to work in my case: `x(1:10)` returns `Error in x(1:10) : unused argument(s) (1:10)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `replicate`

```
replicate(10, x())
```

Also note that you are in **Circle 2**, read [R inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)